# Button inside button (WPF + Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In regular WPF you can have a button inside another button, and to prevent both button events being raised when you click the inner button, you can have the following XAML (As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967576/wpf-button-inside-a-button-click-issue)):

```
<Button Click="OuterClick">
    <Grid>
        <SomeOtherContent />
        <Button Click="InnerClick" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

And then in the code-behind use the Handled property on the event so that OuterClick is not raised when the inner button has been clicked:

```
private void OuterClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // Do something
}
private void InnerClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // Do something else
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

---

However, following the usual Caliburn.Micro conventions you'll have the following XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="OuterClick">
    <Grid>
        <SomeOtherContent />
        <Button x:Name="InnerClick" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

With this in the ViewModel:

```
private void OuterClick() {
    // Do something
}
private void InnerClick() {
    // Do something else
}
```

How can I make sure that not both `InnerClick()` and `OuterClick()` are raised when I click the InnerButton?

EDIT: Or, what other kind of controls can I use instead?

Comment: nested buttons? what kind of nonsense is this. I doubt you will get the the guy who maintains caliburn to adapt to this case, because this kind of scenario is one which will some day be posted on thedailywtf.com ...

Comment: @Sinatr don't skip the "__not__"

Comment: What other component can I have around my `<SomeOtherContent>` and the inner button so that I can attach a click event to the outermost element? I need to have a list with elements, and I need to be able to click an element, but I must also be able to click the button inside the element (without clicking the element itself)?

Comment: @GTHvidsten personally i would not use caliburn to solve that requirement. I've used it before too, but it's only simple if you use basic scenarios. If i were you i would use AttachedProperties which use use preview events to fire a command. While caliburn makes some things easier, it certainly makes some things more difficult - like this

Comment: I'd suggest you to simply change layout: have inner button defined on the same level and overlapping outer.

Comment: Sounds like you want some kind of split button https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. There are a bunch of implementations out there.  For what you're doing, you need a **custom control**.  MVVM does not apply in this situation.  Create a UserControl that handles all your UI nonsense and exposes Commands and DependencyProperties for whatever it needs from your ViewModel.  Handle events in the UC's codebehind.  Remember--MVVM != no codebehind.  Your UI logic goes in your codebehind, not in your view models.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDown]=[Action OuterClick()]">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <SomeotherContent />
        <Button x:Name="InnerClick" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

In Your viewmodel

```
public void OuterClick()
{
    //Do something
}
public void InnerClick()
{
    //Do something
}
```

use stackpanel and apply event for that one.

This will help you.