# How to click a Button inside of a Button? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I created some buttons with another button inside. Then I want to click the inner button but it only throws me the outer button click event, not even both. I tried the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967576/wpf-button-inside-a-button-click-issue) but didn't achieve anything. The exact goal that I have is to only load the click method of the inner button when i click it, and if I click in wherever else in the outer button it throws me the respective method.

```
        //Outer button click event

        void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Stuff
        }
        newBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(newBtn_Click);
        //Inner button click event
        void editButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Stuff
            editButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(editButton_Click);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
     //stuff
```

Comment: Why you added "+=" inside the editButton_Click event handler? it should be added outside that method

Comment: That was the error... I'm sorry. I'll mark your answer as correct as it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to share your code asking a question.

By the way this sample should work:

```
        <Button Background="Red" Width="100" Height="50" Click="Button_Click">
        
        <Button Background="Green" Margin="10" Width="50" Height="50" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        
    </Button>
```

In the event handler of the inner button simply add this, as suggested by the post you mentioned:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

This will stop the chain of [Routed Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) (Bubbling and Tunneling)

Comment: Sorry about the code, I already added it. But the solution in the post didn't work for me. As I said, it runs the outer button's click event but not the inner one.